# Find the transfer function and find the stationary solution associated with $u(t) = \cos(t)$

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

**Problem**

> Given the system
> $$\mathbf{x}'(t)= \begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\mathbf{x}(t)+\begin{bmatrix}0 \\-1 \end{bmatrix}u(t) $$
> $$y(t) = 2x_1(t)-x_2(t) $$
>
> 1. Find the transfer function for the linear system.
> 2. Find the stationary solution associated with $u(t)=\cos(t)$

**My attempt**

1)
The transfer function is easily found with the formula:
$$H(s)=-\mathbf{d}^T(\mathbf{A}-s\mathbf{I})\mathbf{b}$$
We see that $-\mathbf{d}^T= \begin{bmatrix} -2 \\1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{A}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & -1 \\ 3 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$, $\mathbf{b}=\begin{bmatrix}0 \\-1 \end{bmatrix}$, and $\mathbf{I}$ is the identity matrix. Plugging in these values in the formula and using Maple gives
$$H(s)=\frac{s}{s^2-3s+5},s^2-3s+5 \neq0 $$

2)

In my book, it says that the stationary solution associated with $u(t)=e^{st}$ is $y(t)=H(s)e^{st}$.

But what do I do when $u(t)=\cos(t)$?

I have the solution to this problem, and it says that the stationary solution is $y(t)=-\frac{3}{25}\cos(t)-\frac{4}{25}\sin(t)$.

Can someone show me how they arrive at that answer? It seems like you have to plug in a value for $s$, but I'm not sure what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $u(t) = {1 \over 2} (e^{i t} + e^{-i t})$ and get the zero state response
$y(t) = {1 \over 2} (H(i) e^{i t} + H(-i)e^{-i t})$.

Since $H(\overline{s}) = \overline{H(s)}$ we see that
$y(t) = \operatorname{re} H(i) e^{i t} = \operatorname{re} ( (-{3 \over 25} + {4 \over 25}i)(\cos t + i \sin t)$ which simplifies to
$y(t) = -{3 \over 25}\cos t - {4 \over 25} \sin t$.

Answer (score 1):

if you apply a cosine or a sine to a transfer function, the resulting stationary output will be also a cosine or a sine with an altered phase and magnitude. This is because this $s$ can be seen as a frequency variable $s = jw$. This means that if the input of the following form:
$$u(t) = R\text{cos}(wt)$$
the stationary output is something like this:
$$R|H(jw)|cos(wt+\angle H(jw))$$
Hope this helps